# Google+ interactive post - How to use the generated link?

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I would like to open the [Google+ interactive post](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive) dialog through a link instead of the [JavaScript button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive#button_design).
I used Firebug to get this [link](https://apis.google.com/u/0/_/sharebox/dialog?editorText=Come%20learn%20about%20interactive%20posts%20with%20me!&inviteClientId=841077041629.apps.googleusercontent.com&callToActionLabel=INVITE&callToActionUrl=https://developers.google.com/%2b/web/share/interactive?invite=true&isInteractivePost=true&claimedOrigin=https://developers.google.com&url=https://developers.google.com/%2b/web/share/interactive&prm=url&sts=hkxxfc91&susp=true&wpp=1&jsh=m;/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.zhqXaL4QZFs.O/m=__features__/am=IQ/rt=j/d=1/rs=AItRSTOJy01ghUfgNOIwfeaE1xnb4vXxzg#rpctoken=453969578&_methods=_ready,_close,_open,_resizeMe,_renderstart&id=I4_1377777963209&parent=https://developers.google.com&pfname=) which is generated by the Google+ JavaScript.
The problem is that it keeps loading. What parameters do I need to change to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google+ API does not support creating Interactive Posts through a Share URL.  Currently, the only way to access this feature is through our [Share button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive#adding_the_share_button_to_your_page), which you have already discovered. However, you may use a custom button, so long as it adheres to our [branding guidelines](https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines).

Comment: Quick question: Is it possible to share only a text (without a link) through the interactive post feature? https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive